# React Native, global useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, expo, state

I have a Fire class, and the `uid` return undefined if the user is not connected, string (his uid) if he is connected.

Sometime my render depend on this.

For example :

```js
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<undefined|string>(Fire.shared.uid);

[...]

<Text>{(auth == undefined) ? "not authentificated" : "great")}</Text>
```

We can imagine the user is not connect so the text will be `not authentificated`.
Now he will Sign in or Sign up in an other page, so the uid variable in `Fire` class will change.
So how I'm suppose to change the state value?

There is no useState global or something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use context:

> page-context.js

```
export const PageContext= React.createContext();
```

> app.js

```
const App = () => {
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<undefined|string>(undefined);

return(
    <PageContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>
       <NavigationContainer> // your routes
    </PageContext.Provider>)
```

> OtherScreen.js

```
function OtherScreen() {
    const [auth] = useContext(PageContext);
    return (<Text>{(auth == undefined) ? "not authentificated" : "great")}</Text>)
}
```

> Sign.js

```
 function Sign() {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useContext(PageContext);
    return (<Button onPress={()=>setAuth("myUid)} />)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use react js context api to have this feature : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component,

or you can use third party libraries like redux or mobx to have a global state

redux : https://redux.js.org/
mobx : https://mobx.js.org/README.html